# Python data copier

Tags: python, image, image-processing

http://nifty.stanford.edu/2012/guerin-image-editor/ I am trying to complete the above task. I need help with phase 1. I am trying to get my program to read in one bufferful, write it out to the output file, and repeat the process until the input is exhausted. My code doesn't return any error when run in python but it is unable to write the header info of the ppm image file to a text file . How would I do that?

```
class PPM():
    def __init__(self, infile, outfile):
        self.infile=infile
        self.oufile=outfile

        #Read in data of image
        data= open(self.infile,"r")
        datain=data.read()
        splits=datain.split()

        #Header info
        self.type=splits[0]
        self.columns=splits[1]
        self.row=splits[2]
        self.colour=splits[3]
        self.pixels=splits[:4]

    def writeOut(self):
        dataout=open(self.outfile, "w")



sample= PPM("cake.ppm", "Replica.ppm")
```

Comment: Why are there three answers from @user3204229, each with a single upvote?

Comment: @CodyPiersall that user also asks a question regarding the same homework assignment here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21271980/flipping-images-in-python - maybe they know each other?

Comment: @PeterGibson I think you're on to something.  The user offered a substantial bounty; maybe he was trying to get the reputation needed, so answered a bunch of times and his friend upvoted him.  Probably working through some homework together.

Comment: @CodyPiersall: Merged accounts, probably. If a moderator merged the sock puppets into one, then we *now* see them all as one. The upvotes have since been removed as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
self.type=splits[0]
self.columns=splits[1]
self.row=splits[2]
self.colour=splits[3]
self.pixels=splits[4:]
```

def negate_red(self):
    for b in range (0, (len(self.pixels)) , 3):
        remainder=abs(255-self.colour)

Answer (score 0):

```
    else:
        temp_list = []
        for b in range(int(self.row)):
            column_list = []
            column_list += self.pixels[0:int(self.columns) * 3]
            self.pixels = self.pixels[int(self.columns) * 3 : ]
            temp_list.append(column_list)
        #print temp_list
        new_list = []
        for i in range(int(len(temp_list))):
            new_list.append (temp_list[i][0])
            new_list.append (temp_list[i][1])
            new_list.append (temp_list[i][2])
            temp_list[i] = temp_list[i][::-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def writetofile(self):
        dataout= open(self.outfile,"w")
        dataout.write(self.type +"\n" + self.columns + "\n" + self.row +"\n"+ self.colour +"\n"+ " ".join (self.pixels))def writetofile(self):
        dataout= open(self.outfile,"w")
        dataout.write(self.type +"\n" + self.columns + "\n" + self.row +"\n"+ self.colour +"\n"+ " ".join (self.pixels))
```